# iMessage like group messaging

Tags: sms

My friends with iphones frequently group message me and I am never able to participate because when i hit reply it only sends the message back to the original person sending the message, not the whole group. Does stock android have a feature that allows us to group message other iphone users the way they group message one another?

If it helps I'm running an alpha version (albeit stable) of CM10.1 (android 4.2) on a Motorola Atrix.

Comment: No, the stock messaging app has no way of knowing who was it from regardless of platform. Alternative is to suggest to other apple users to use whatsapp or viber and use that instead I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I am on 2.3.5

In the basic "messages" app you can go to the message, clicknhold, view message details. There it shows all recipients.

There is a "reply all" option after you click and hold.